# Hide & show a widget using Jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, symfony1, hide, show

In my form created with symfony 1.4, I have a `sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice` in which I choose one of options, I want to hide some field & show them until my choice was token.

Comment: Please don't put tags in the title. That's what the tag field is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe u should write this code:
$('#model_id_table').closest("td").find('label').hide();

*td if your widget is set in table,u can use any other tag.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have problems with widget's name.

So, Visit this Link for more informations :
http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: Consider posting a relevant excerpt from the article you link to.

Comment: to call a widget in javascript i use :
$('#model_id_table').hide('fast');

Comment: the instruction i use, hide the widget but its label still showen

Comment: you may have to call `$('#model_id_table').parent().hide('fast');`

Comment: $('#model_id_table').closest("label").hide('fast');

Comment: Both of suggestions doesn't work :

Neither this : $('#model_id_table').parent().hide('fast');

Nor this : $('#model_id_table').closest("label").hide('fast');